# Express js use values from mongodb to outside of the query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new with express js and node js. I am wonder if its possible to do this or not.

1st thing I'm trying to get the count on 1 query.

2nd I query collection login. loop it and format and get the name values using ids.

I get undefined on count1 and I see it ommitted on the json response.

how do I pass the query returns outside of the query?

```
router.post('/logmein', function(req, res, next) {
    var email = req.param('email');
    var password = req.param('password');
    var count1;

    MongoClient.connect(MongoUrl, function(err, db) {
        if (err) return;

        db.collection('users').count({email: email,password: md5(password)}, function(err, count) {
            count1 = count;
        });

        db.collection('login').find({email: email,password: md5(password)}).toArray(function(err, results){
            console.log(results); // output all records
        });


        //use results
        /*
        foreach each results format with other info

        var new_array;
        */
        res.json({"success": true,"count":count1,new_array: new_array});
    }); 
});
```

Comment: what error are you getting when you try to execute the above code ? did you try simply returning the results instead of printing it to console ?

Comment: I get undefined on variable count1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async issues, you have to look more at it. Use the [async module](http://caolan.github.io/async/) and then you will be able to fire the queries in parallel. Finally, you will have the results in the final callback. This snippet will fix your issue:

```
var async = require('async');

router.post('/logmein', function (req, res, next) {
  var email = req.param('email');
  var password = req.param('password');
  var retResults;
  var count1;

  MongoClient.connect(MongoUrl, function (err, db) {
    if (err) return;

    async.parallel([
      function(callback){ 
        db.collection('users').count({ email: email, password: md5(password) }, function (err, count) {
          return callback(err, count);
        });
      },
      function(callback){
        db.collection('login').find({ email: email, password: md5(password) }).toArray(function (err, results) {
          return callback(err, results);
        });
      }
    ], function(err, results) {
      if (err) {
        // @todo: handle the error
      }

      count1 = results[0];
      retResults = results[1];


      //use results
      /*
      foreach each results format with other info

      var new_array;
      */
      res.json({ "success": true, "count": count1, new_array: new_array });

    };
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting undefined for count1 and retResults still.

Comment: also when I tried to put console.log(retResults); the call doesnt end.

Comment: @LJBoy I forgot to type the callbacks. Just fixed it, you try again.

Comment: oh thanks. I also placed res.json({ "success": true, "count": count1, new_array: new_array }); inside the last function. it didnt work outside.

Comment: @LJBoy yes just noticed it and moved it. If you are happy, you can accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need something like [async.parallel](http://caolan.github.io/async/) to control the async flow of your nodejs application

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback){ ... },
    function(callback){ ... }
], function(err, results) {
    // optional callback
};
```